# How to implement Nuxt Server Middleware Google authorization?

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I've got the following auth configuration in my `nuxt.config.js`

```js
auth: {
  strategies: {
    google: {
      client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_KEY,
      codeChallengeMethod: '',
      scope: ['profile', 'email'],
      responseType: 'token id_token'
    }
  },
  redirect: {
    login: '/login',
    logout: '/logout',
    home: '/',
    callback: '/welcome'
  },
  rewriteRedirects: false
},
router: {
  middleware: ['auth']
},
serverMiddleware: [
  { path: '/db', handler: '~/api/db.js' },
],
```

This setups frontend authentication, so all my `.vue` pages are protected. Besides that, I've got some serverMiddleware, like in my `api/db.js`

```js
const app = require('express')()

app.get('/fields/:schema', async (req, res) => {
  var result = []
  // some logics here
  return result;
})
```

Request to this resource is not protected by any auth, but I've noticed in Network tab in browser, that all request made by `$axios.$get('db/fields/some_schema')` from my `.vue` pages set some Google cookie, like

```
auth.strategy=google; auth._token.google=Bearer...
```

which is not used in my serverMiddleware `api/db.js`

Does Nuxt.js has some out of box way to setup Google authentication for server middleware? What is the right way to setup it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use this nuxt config

```
  auth: {
 strategies: {
   google: {
    clientId: 'to be added',
    clientId: '<your cliendID here>',
    codeChallengeMethod: '',
    responseType: 'code',
    endpoints: {
      token: 'http://localhost:8000/social-login/google/',
      userInfo: 'http://localhost:8000/auth/user/'
    },
   },
 }
},
```

and implement backend token and userInfo endpoints